# Typescript interfaces, type object

Tags: typescript

```
{
  title: 'my title',
  subtitle: 'my subtitle',
  description: 'my description',
  link: {
    title: 'my link title',
    uri: 'my link uri'
  }
}
```

I want to format this using interface. I tried proceding like so without success :

```
export interface BlockRight {
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  description: string;
  link: Link;
}

interface Link {
  title: string;
  uri: string;
}
```

`link`doesn't seem to be valid. How can I create an interface for this json structure? Thanks.

Comment: *'link doesn't seem to be valid'* - how so? Please elaborate on what the issue is.

Comment: Tried on playground works fine ..

Comment: `content = {} as BlockRight;` `ngOnInit() { this.content.link.title = 'test'; }` It will returns `cannot set property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: The issue isn't with your types, it's your code - you've not set `this.content.link` to anything, so it's undefined when you try to set it.

Comment: I don't understand how should I set `this.content.link` or what should it be set to?

Comment: That JS error is becuase you must define `link` as an object before you can assign any of its own properties. You can do this all at once `this.content.link = { title: 'test', uri: 'test' }`. However this is irrelevant, as you are bypassing any of the type safety anyway by using `as BlockRight`. The correct usage of interface would be `content: BlockRight` although this would fail type safety because you will be missing many required properties. But this is great, as you wouldn't accidentally get to this error state anyway (which is kinda the desirable usage of typescript no?)

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate your link property first before assigning anything:

```
interface Link {
 title: string;
 uri: string;
}

interface BlockRight {
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  description: string;
  link: Link;
}

let block: BlockRight = {} as BlockRight;

block.title = 'title';
block.subtitle = "subtitle";
block.description = 'description';
block.link = {} as Link;
block.link.title = 'google';
block.link.uri = 'https://google.com';
console.log(block);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following. Optional attributes should be declared with ? following them like I have declared description in following example.

```
export interface BlockRight {
title: string;
subtitle: string;
description?: string;
link: Link;
}
interface Link {
title: string;
uri: string;
}

let blockRight:BlockRight = {title:"MyTitle", subtitle:"My Subtitle", description: "MyDescription", link: {title: "My Link Title", uri:"mypath"}};
```